# Native bitmap processing and ALPHA_8

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to convert an image to grayscale through a native function, using a piece of code taken from *Android in Action* (2nd ed.; you can also see it [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-androidndk/os-androidndk-pdf.pdf)). Unfortunately, the returned bitmap object, instead of grayscale, ends up empty.

This is how I load the (.png) image:

```
Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.sample, options);
```

There is a number of safety conditions that the bitmap passes (please check below). Here's the native function definition in Java:

```
public native void convertToGray(Bitmap bitmapIn,Bitmap bitmapOut);
```

and the call:

```
// Grayscale bitmap (initially empty)     
Bitmap gray = Bitmap.createBitmap(original.getWidth(),original.getHeight(),Config.ALPHA_8);
// Native function call
convertToGray(original,gray);
```

And here's the function:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_Preprocessor_convertToGray(JNIEnv * env, jobject  obj, jobject bitmapcolor,jobject bitmapgray)
{
    AndroidBitmapInfo infocolor;
    AndroidBitmapInfo infogray; 
    void* pixelscolor;
    void* pixelsgray;
    int ret;
    int y;
    int x;    

    LOGI("convertToGray");
    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmapcolor, &infocolor)) < 0) {
        LOGE("AndroidBitmap_getInfo() failed ! error=%d", ret);
        return;
    }    

    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmapgray, &infogray)) < 0) {
        LOGE("AndroidBitmap_getInfo() failed ! error=%d", ret);
        return;
    }

    LOGI("color image :: width is %d; height is %d; stride is %d; format is %d;flags is %d",infocolor.width,infocolor.height,infocolor.stride,infocolor.format,infocolor.flags);
    if (infocolor.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888) {
        LOGE("Bitmap format is not RGBA_8888 !");
        return;
    }  

    LOGI("gray image :: width is %d; height is %d; stride is %d; format is %d;flags is %d",infogray.width,infogray.height,infogray.stride,infogray.format,infogray.flags);
    if (infogray.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_A_8) {
        LOGE("Bitmap format is not A_8 !");
        return;
    }   

    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmapcolor, &pixelscolor)) < 0) {
        LOGE("AndroidBitmap_lockPixels() failed ! error=%d", ret);
    }

    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmapgray, &pixelsgray)) < 0) {
        LOGE("AndroidBitmap_lockPixels() failed ! error=%d", ret);
    }

    // modify pixels with image processing algorithm
    for (y=0;y<infocolor.height;y++) {
        argb * line = (argb *) pixelscolor;
        uint8_t * grayline = (uint8_t *) pixelsgray;
        for (x=0;x<infocolor.width;x++) {
            grayline[x] = 0.3 * line[x].red + 0.59 * line[x].green + 0.11*line[x].blue;
        }

        pixelscolor = (char *)pixelscolor + infocolor.stride;
        pixelsgray = (char *) pixelsgray + infogray.stride;
    }

    LOGI("Done! Unlocking pixels...");
    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmapcolor);
    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmapgray);
}
```

The color bitmap gets passed correctly, and the processing part of the code appears to be working fine, but *bitmapgray* stays empty. I guess I'm missing something crucial here.

Test environment: emulator, v2.2. With this version, the function works when the native code is called from the **main thread**. On a 2.3 emulator, the function doesn't work **regardless of the thread** that calls the C code, or the way the bitmap is loaded. Android NDK: 4b & 6b.

> **UPDATE #1:** You'll find the complete source code [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/apps/download/index.jsp?contentid=646128&filename=os-androidndk-IBMPhotoPhun.source.zip&method=http&locale=).
>
> **UPDATE #2:** RGB_565 instead of ALPHA_8 gives some results. It appears not even setPixels() in Java works for ALPHA_8, and I'm having
>   problems finding info on this config type. Any kind of help would be
>   much appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered trying to use a ByteBuffer as output? If that works, then we could be more sure there is something wrong with AndroidBitmap... Also are `bitmapIn`, `bitmapOrig` and `original` the same object?

Comment: I'm entirely new to JNI, so no, I haven't tried it. I will give it a shot and then report back. I would still be thankful for some tips or directions that could speed up the process. And, yes, bitmapIn = bitmapOrig = original (sorry about the latter two; I should've made it clearer; fixed it).

Comment: @SamuelAudet: OK, I tried [this one](http://imrannazar.com/Augmented-Reality-with-the-Android-NDK:-Part-2). The result is an *almost* blank bitmap (a white surface with black artifacts (random black dots)). Would anyone else be kind enough to give this a shot?

Comment: And you are not getting any warnings or anything in the log?

Comment: @SamuelAudet: No, nothing. grayline[x] calculation definitely works and, therefore, pixelsgray should get populated with correct values as well. However, bitmapgray remains empty.

Comment: @SamuelAudet I tried removing the infogray.format safety condition, and then passed bitmapgray to the function as an RGB_565 image, and actually got something back (the image was all scrambled, but this is not surprising). So, the problem appears to be in ALPHA_8. The funny thing is that sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't (as explained above).

Comment: It appears not even setPixels() in Java works for ALPHA_8, and I'm having problems finding info on this config type.

Comment: Anyone? I would greatly appreciate some help with ALPHA_8, at least. Is there anything specific related to this config type?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem.
First of all, I used android RGBA_8888 format for infogray instead of A_8 (the original bitmap was created using ARGB_8888 format).
Then if you use argb struct for grayline instead of uint_8, you can fill the pixels like this:

```
for (y = 0; y < infocolor.height; ++y) {
       argb* line = (argb*) pixelscolor;
       argb* grayline = (argb*) pixelsgray;
       for (x = 0; x < infocolor.width; ++x) {         
          grayline[x].red = grayline[x].green = grayline[x].blue = 0.3 * line[x].red + 0.59 * line[x].green + 0.11 * line[x].blue;
       }
       pixelscolor = (char*)pixelscolor + infocolor.stride;
       pixelsgray = (char*)pixelsgray + infogray.stride;
   }
```

Comment: Well, it does give some results, but the output image is blueish. I was hoping to use A_8 to save some memory (I'd like to try some real-time image processing).

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problems. 
I did not try much to make ALPHA_8 work but using ARGB_8888 fixes the problem.

Btw, in reply to @white_pawn's comment (sorry i cannot reply to comments)

The argb struct in [IBM's](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-androidndk/section5.html) example is in wrong order. in my emulators or phone, 
converting it to RGBA fixes the issue (this is probably the reason why your image looks blue because you use alpa for blue). Though I'm not sure if this order is hardware dependent.

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t red;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t alpha;
} argb;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found what went wrong! When you use APHA_8 you need to change background to **#ffffffff**,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffffff">
```